# How to update FXML button using setText in java - when it returns java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am fairly new to java. I want to update a button's text using a class so when the method is called it updates accordingly. I've tried to implement some of the code from other relevant posts but can't figure it out. First of all - do you have to update the whole scene in order to update a button or does it work like react where it updates parts of the DOM?

The goal is to update the text of the button when the scene loads.
FXML file:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="project.Controller">
<Button fx:id="button" text="STOP"></Button> 
</AnchorPane>
```

Primary Java file:

```
public class project extends Application { 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(project.class.getResource("index.fxml"));
             Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 750);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            Controller editButton = new Controller();
            editButton.editButtonText("blabla selected");


        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Class file:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable
{   

    //FXML
   @FXML public Button button;


   @FXML
   public void editButtonText(String text){
    //   button = new Button();
       button.setText(text);
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle r){

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Controller editButton = new Controller();
editButton.editButtonText("blabla selected");
```

The problem is that part. Once you load the fxml file with the FXMLLoader, a new controller object is automatically created. You can access that controller object by using

```
Controller editButton = (Controller) loader.getController`
```

Otherwise you reference a new Conctroller, that doesn't have a GUI assigned to it.

Alternatively, you could also write it as:

```
Controller controller = new Controller();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(project.class.getResource("index.fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load()
```

That way, your newly created Controller object is set as the FXMLController for the fxml file you are about to load. **Notice**: for this to work, the controller can not be set in the fxml file.

Comment: But isn't the controller referenced in the xml document with fx:controller="project.Controller" ?

Comment: yes, the controller class is referenced in your fxml. When the loader loads your fxml, it creates a new controller object for that gui, which you can then receive by using loader.getController.

The other Controller you create is not bound to any view, therefore the null pointer.

Comment: When i add your alternative code - it says "javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified."

Comment: If you want to use my alternativ code, you should remove fx:controller="project.Controller" from your fxml file, then it works.

Comment: yeah okay. It's working now. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer ;)